# C++, как сделать строку нечитаемой в hex

Tags: c++, hex

Есть программа в которой определяется переменная типа string. После ее определения в hex editor'е присутствует эта строка. Вопрос: возможно ли сделать ее нечитаемой, как?

Comment: Это же C++, конечно всё возможно. [Изучайте](https://www.blackhat.com/docs/eu-14/materials/eu-14-Andrivet-C-plus-plus11-Metaprogramming-Applied-To-software-Obfuscation-wp.pdf) - variadic templates, constexpr и немножко макросов творят чудеса.

Comment: Не уверен, просто самому интересно стало, сработает ли такое: а что если представить строку в виде, например, массива символов, а перед непосредственным использованием строки "восстанавливать" ее? Такое сработает?

Comment: Способов масса, любые [обратимые] логические операции типа XOR.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну зашифруйте ее, но перед употреблением не забудьте расшифровать.
Например, просто сдвиньте на 1 символ -

```
string s = "Ifmmp-!xpsme\"";
for(auto&c: s) --c;
```

И работайте с вашей `Hello, world!` :)

Comment: Мб есть другой способ, дабы хранить данные в их первоначальном виде?

Comment: Знаете, у меня вы сегодня второй, который заявляет - ничего не хочу делать, но хочу, чтоб было по-моему!... Даешь решение - а он в ответ: хочу так, как я написал! Компилятор не компилирует, рассказываешь, как сделать - "а может, есть другой способ, чтоб работало, как я написал?"...

Comment: Я не говорю, что хочу чтобы было как по моему, а уточняю есть ли другие варианты.

Comment: @TheJustGus Ха, а как вы себе представляете противоречие "хочу чтобы было зашифровано, но чтобы было первоначально видно"? Выберите что-то одно: либо чтобы было видно, либо чтобы не было видно. Сразу и то и то -- ну, как-то вызывает сомнения в логике спрашивающего. Максимум, что можно сделать - это давать константам/ресурсам говорящие имена, как вообще и полагается делать в интернационализированных программах.

Comment: Есть и другие. Использовать `xor`, таблицу подстановок или еще какой способ шифрования... Кстати, в конце-концов, запакуйте исполнимый файл упаковщиком exe - тоже метод...

Comment: @A K, всё это возможно - достаточно сделать `OBF("Hello");` и написать корректный макрос `OBF`. В своём ответе я дал ссылку на теорию и реализацию.